# How to check uniqueness of particular elements of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I have a class called LineUp, it is an ArrayList of a class called Event. An Event has three values a String Act, a Venue (it's own class), and an int Session.

An Event might be declared like this. 
Event e1 = new Event("Foo Fighters", northstage, "1")
LineUp is an ArrayList, Event being elements like e1.

In my LineUp class I have to make an invariant that checks that every Event contained within the ArrayList lineup has a unique Venue and Session. Because this assignment requires that I follow specification exactly, it is irrelevant whether the combination of Act, Venue and Session is unique, to follow specification I must /only/ ensure that Venue and Session are unique.

How do I check for duplicates but only of specific values within an ArrayList?

Thank-you.

Comment: Override the hashcode (and equals) method of your Event to generate a unquie value based on its contents (I like using Apaches Commons API to do this, but most IDEs should be able to do it for you) and the use some kind of Set (like HashSet for example) which will gurentee unquiness of the items beyond simple "==" comparisons

Comment: Do you have to use ArrayList? Set seems more appropriate, it will not allow you to insert same Event, 'sameness' you can define by overriding `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods

Comment: Here's where it gets annoying and weird. The specification (Which I am unable to edit, but must obey) in Event requires that Session Venue /and/ Act must be equal for an Event to be equal. But there is a specification within Lineup that says if Venue and Session are the same for an event within the lineup arraylist, this is not allowed. So I can't modify the Event equals method and it's specification is different. So I don't think I can use that method of checking, do you have any alternatives?
Also I do have to use arraylist because order is important at different times

Comment: So just to clarify Events are equal if session, venue and act are equal. And in Lineup you need to remove Events that only have unique venue-session pair, right?

Comment: Not remove them, just return false on an invariant if there are duplicates of venue-session pairs. In other words, within Lineup venue-session pairs should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to check if there are duplicates (considering venue-session pairs), you could create a helper `Pair` class with only the attributes that matter in this specific case. Then `map` the events to `Pair` objects, remove the duplicates and check if the size is the same.

You could, for example, create a nested class inside `LineUp`:

```
class LineUp {
    private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final class Pair<U, V> {
        final U first;
        final V second;

        Pair(U first, V second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(o instanceof Pair)) {
                return false;
            }
            Pair<U, V> that = (Pair<U, V>) o;
            return Objects.equals(this.first, that.first)
                    && Objects.equals(this.second, that.second);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(this.first, this.second);
        }
    }

    // rest of the LineUp class
}
```

Then create a method that return false if there are any duplicates:

```
public boolean duplicateVenueSessions() {
    // Map each Event to a Pair<Venue, Integer> and remove the duplicates
    long numDistinct = this.events.stream()
                                  .map(e -> new Pair<>(e.venue, e.session))
                                  .distinct()
                                  .count();
    // return false if the original number of events is different from the
    // number of distinct events considering only venue and session values
    return this.events.size() != numDistinct;
}
```

If can't use Java 8, you could use a `Set` instead:

```
public boolean duplicateVenueSessions() {
    Set<Pair<String, Integer>> distinct = new HashSet<>();
    for (Event e : this.events) {
        Pair<String, Integer> venueSession = new Pair<>(e.venue, e.session);
        if (distinct.contains(venueSession)) {
            return true;
        }
        distinct.add(venueSession);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand everything correctly you can use Map in a method to store values

```
Map<Map<Venue, Integer>, Act> lineup = new HashMap<>();
```

it incorporated uniqueness of Venue-Session pair.

However as Venue is your own class, you will have to implement equals() and hashCode() methods for Venue in order for this solution to work

EDIT:

what I meant wa something like this:

```
    Map<Map<Integer, Venue>,String> uniqueMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Event event: events) { // assuming events is ArrayList
        Map<Integer, Venue> sessionVenueMap = new HashMap<>();
        sessionVenueMap.put(event.getSession(), event.getVenue());

        //check if we stored this pair in our cool map
        if (uniqueMap.get(sessionVenueMap) == null) {
            //if not
            //store this in our uniqieMap in our method
            uniqueMap.put(sessionVenueMap, event.getAct);
            sessionVenueMap.put(event.getSession(), event.getVenue);
        } else {
            // if map has this pair
            // then it is not unique
            return false;
        }
        venueSessionMap.put(.getVenue(); event.getSession();
    }
    return true;
```

code is not tested though, but you get the general idea, although it seems quite complex. probably there is a better solution

Comment: I have implemented equals and hashcode for Venue. 
Sorry, just some clarification are you using I could use this use HashMap in the same way I would use HashSet in an implementation similar to MadProgrammer's comment? --- I am just discovering "Map" types now. 

How would I go about putting the elements of the lineup arraylist into the lineup hashmap?